# What is the difference between `lineFragmentRect` and `lineFragmentUsedRect`?

Tags: ios, macos, textkit

What is the difference between [`NSLayoutManager.lineFragmentRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403140-linefragmentrect) and [`NSLayoutManager.lineFragmentUsedRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403193-linefragmentusedrect)?

Comment: I checked the docs... still no idea. I guess it depends on what the difference is between the `rectangle` and `usage rectangle`. But they don't seem to define that anywhere.

Comment: First step should always be **searching**. First result comes up with this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/692138 which appears to show the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`lineFragmentUsedRect` is the part of with actual characters. This is used for drawing the background when text is selected for example. The `lineFragmentRect` is always larger and usually holds the rectangle for the entire width of the view.